# LDR / photoresistor issue: resistance is constant in different light conditions

Tags: arduino, atmega328p, ldr, plc, photoresistor

I have installation with [Controllino mini](https://controllino.biz/product/controllino-mini/), it's essentially an ATmega328, and with 6 LDRs and 6 lasers, creating laser rays/barriers.

The system acts as a lasers labyrinth for entertainment purposes, and it's working for approximately a year.
One of the LDR's - just generic one you can buy in every [electronics component shop](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9088), stopped working as it should.
Meaning - it outputs constant voltage no matter what are the light conditions.
The installation of the sensor consists of +12V input on one pole, and connection to the ATmega328 based PLC analog input on the another pole with a 10K resistor to GND.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1XCrC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After taking it apart, the measured resistance on the LDR was constant (don't remember the exact value) and not reacting to different light conditions.
I did replace this sensor, but after a week or so, the same problem occurred again.

This, and the fact that it was working for a year without issues, made me believe there might be external factor affecting it/ taking it out of order.

Why did the LDR or circuit fail after a long period of time?

Comment: I'm not sure LDRs were ever really mean to be blasted with lasers...

Comment: It`s a 5v@25ma red dot 650 nM Laser.
All sensors/LDR`s are working for more then a year, without issues. Only this one stopped working normally after 12 months of operation.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this is the cause of LDR failure, but your circuit has a basic flaw: A +12v supply can cause damage to the ATmega328, when the photo-resistor's resistance is low enough to raise the Analog input pin above ATmega328's Vdd (+5v?). Too much current can flow.
The solution is to lower the +12v supply to no more than ATmega328's Vdd voltage. You may have to lower the threshold where you decide if the laser beam has been blocked, because with a lower supply, your circuit will be less sensitive.

Comment: Hi Glen thanks for answering.
Its an Atmega based PLC. I`ve attached link above.
Normal operating voltages for it`s IOs are 12/24V.

Comment: @Eli It would appear that the PLC analog input conditioning makes your circuit OK. I can only suggest that Trevor's suggestion of concentrated laser power might cause spot overheating. A de-focused beam might help.